# How to create mentioned specific JSON format

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

This is the JSON format which I am getting through the API.

**Currently generated JSON format**

```
[
  {
    "question":"q1",
    "option":"a"
  },
  {
    "question":"q1",
    "option":"b"
  },
  {
    "question":"q1",
    "option":"c"
  },
  {
    "question":"q1",
    "option":"d"
  },
  {
    "question":"q2",
    "option":"a"
  },
  {
    "question":"q2",
    "option":"b"
  }
]
```

After receiving and converting the above json formar, I want to send the below json format.
but I am facing issue to creating below mentioned json format.
suppose the **list**  contains above JSON format then what I have tried is:

```
List finalList = new ArrayList();
list.stream.forEach(k - > {
    List optionList = new ArrayList();
    Map m = new HashMap();
    if (!m.containsKey(k.getQuestion)) {
        m.put("ques", k.getQuestion());
    }
    optionList.add(k.getOption());
    m.put("option", optionList);
    finalList.add(m);
})
System.out.println(finalList);
```

but above code is not returning specific prefered JSON format.

**JSON format which I want to generate**

```
[
  {
    "question":"q1",
    "option":[
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  },
  {
    "question":"q2",
    "option":[
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? If so, can you show us and explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Deserialize, normalize and serialize again

Comment: The format you specified is not valid JSON. Strings have to be surrounded in quotes.

Comment: @Derlin I have tried using iterating the list and check whether the question is available in map as a key if not then add a question and corresponding option but it is not working

Comment: ok, so show us the code then so we can help

Comment: Please [edit] the question (do not put code in comments). Add the code you used, and explain what "not working" means. Does it throw an error? If so, include the full error - formatted as code - and point which line it happens in. If not, does it work incorrectly? Explain exactly what it does that it shouldn't have done.

Comment: @Derlin I have modified my question with the code which I had tried myself, please help.

Comment: @Derlin Can you understand my code now, if yes then please try to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create java pojos for both JSON structures. pojo for source structure:

```java
class SourceData {
    private String question;
    private String option;
    // getters and setters
}
```

2. Target JSON pojo:

```java
class TargetData {
    private String question;
    private List<String> options;
    // getters and setters
}
```

3. Serialize source json to pojos

```java
List<SourceData> sourceDatas = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<SourceData>>() {});
```

4. Traverse through source pojo objects and transform to target pojos

```java
List<TargetData> targetDatas = new ArrayList<>();

sourceDatas.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getQuestion()))
    .forEach((question, itemList) -> {
        TargetData targetData = new TargetData();
        targetData.setQuestion(question);
        List<String> options = itemList.stream().map(SourceData::getOption).collect(Collectors.toList());
        targetData.setOptions(options);
        targetDatas.add(targetData);
    });
```